# How do I divide my screen in 2 equal parts using constraint layout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I would like to divide my screen in two halves using constraint layout? I can only find examples for relative and linear layouts could someone help me out? I attached a screenshot as to how I would like it to look.[Image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T86fw.jpg)

Comment: `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"` on the two widgets to have their heights each take up half of the overall `ConstraintLayout` height.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this is to use a `<GuideLine />`

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="50%"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <TextView
            android:text="Text 1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

    <TextView
            android:text="Text 2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

For more information on android constraint layout guidelines, you can read their official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Guideline)

[Here's](https://pusher.com/tutorials/constraintlayout-kotlin-part-3#guidelines) another great article for learning on how to used guidelines